# How to show tags on Amazon AWS invoice

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Using Amazon Aws for ec2 I know I can make tags that then are showed on the aws console and can even gave the ec2 ‘s a name in the console. I am wondering if there is a way to show the valie from the ec2 name column or the value of any custom tags I made on the aws bill. I am trying to find a way to better identify for our accounting department how much each of our clients resources are costing us.

Suggestions? Or how do other companies handle this?

Comment: Try this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/tags-billing-cost-center-project/ . I don't think it's possible to get the onto your invoice, it would be too complex. but the easiest way is to have one account per workload per environment, if that suits your AWS resources. You can also use a third party tool like CloudHealth.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [Cost Allocation Tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html) to gain visibility and manage your costs.

Hope this helps!